# describe spark table/view comment

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

We can create a table and view it with a comment describing it.
For example (from [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html#examples)):

```
CREATE TABLE student (id INT, name STRING, age INT) USING CSV
    COMMENT 'this is a comment'
    TBLPROPERTIES ('foo'='bar');
```

**How can you retrieve the comment in a "clean format"?**
**By clean format, I mean only (or almost only) the table name and the comment describing it.** Any other solution I've found bloats me with all the column types and information (which I don't need in this case).

I've tried:

```
DESCRIBE student
DESCRIBE EXTENDED student
SHOW CREATE TABLE student
DESCRIBE DETAIL student -- databricks only
SHOW VIEWS FROM default -- to try seeing views description
SHOW TABLES FROM default -- to try seeing tables description
```

The best would be to have something like `SHOW TABLE`/`SHOW VIEWS`, but with a column adding the description.

Is there an out-of-the-box solution for this? If not, is there a good custom way to achieve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get table comment only. However it's fairly easy to filter it out of `DESCRIBE TABLE` statement using Scala.

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE student (id INT, name STRING, age INT) USING CSV COMMENT 'this is a comment'")
spark.sql("DESCRIBE TABLE EXTENDED student").filter($"col_name" === "Comment").show

+--------+-----------------+-------+
|col_name|        data_type|comment|
+--------+-----------------+-------+
| Comment|this is a comment|       |
+--------+-----------------+-------+
```